# can't create many pdf files using dompdf

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I'm trying to create many pdf files using a loop and put them in a specific place, but I'm getting this error:

```
DOMPDF_Exception

File:
C:\wamp\www\leadmarket\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\include\inline_positioner.cls.php:37
Message:
No block-level parent found.  Not good.
```

Here is my code:

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < 3 ; $i++){
    $pdf = new PdfModel();
    $pdf->setOption("paperSize", "a4"); //Defaults to 8x11
    $pdfView = new ViewModel($pdf);
    $pdfView->setTerminal(true)
            ->setTemplate('application/annonceur/generer-facture-mensuelle.phtml')
            ->setVariables(array(
                'client' => $i
                )
            );
    $html = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewpdfrenderer')->getHtmlRenderer()->render($pdfView);
    $eng = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewpdfrenderer')->getEngine();

    $eng->load_html($html);
    $eng->render();
    $pdfCode = $eng->output();
    file_put_contents('public/folder/file-'.$i'.pdf', $pdfCode); 
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using TCPDF instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dompdf currently only supports rendering a single document per instance ([issue #1056](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1056)). Until this issue is resolved you'll need to unset the Dompdf instance and create a new one.

It looks like you're creating an instance per loop of your `PdfModel` and `ViewModel`, but the Dompdf instance is part of the class that contains your loop (`$this->getServiceLocator...`).

I'm not familiar with the framework you're using, so I can't give you a specific answer. The quickest solution would be to not use the Dompdf instance that's part of your ServiceLocator instance.

Replace

```
$eng = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewpdfrenderer')->getEngine();
```

With

```
$eng = new Dompdf();
$eng->setOption("paperSize", "a4");
```

As you see the paper size had to be set again, and that's the drawback. Any options configured in the ServiceLocator will be lost.

Comment: Just a point , i'm using zf2 so for those who can be facing the same problem i replaced it by $eng = new \DOMPDF(); :)